# Can I uninstall the Messages Beta?

Tags: ichat, macos, messages

I'm thinking about trying the [Messages Beta](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/messages-beta/) on OS X Lion. I'm wondering if I will be able to uninstall it if I don't want to use it anymore. If so, will I be able to use iChat again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes.**

In the Messages menu, there's an option to uninstall the beta. Apple just messes with the App bundle to add support for the iMessage protocol. The underlying app is pretty much the same.

See [this AskDifferent Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41522/what-will-happen-to-ichat-in-lion-once-messages-beta-expired) and [this post](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2012/02/messages-is-really-really-really-ichat/) which it references for more information.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that it will be Mountain Lion only? Reference please. I'd bet differently.

Comment: @jaberg - Not for certain, but it's likely. See my added links for more.

Comment: None of those links provide any evidence that Messages will be Mountain Lion only.

Comment: @jaberg - That's true. Wouldn't the fact that it's listed as a ML feature imply that, though?

Comment: Not necessarily. My guess as a relatively experienced Apple watcher is that if the beta works on Lion, there will be a version for Lion.

Comment: @jaberg - You're possibly right. Edited, better?

Comment: It's your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose uninstall Messages Beta from the menu.

[image]